# sharepoint 2010 access page with impersonation

Tags: 2010, impersonation

This may not be explicitly a sharepoint issue, but since it's being used to access a sharepoint page I thought I'd ask here.

Trying to access a page in a sharepoint site (eventually a results page from advanced search, on the off chance that matters of there's an easier way to do it) which is set up to use windows authentication.  Using the following test code from another site to pass with username and password of a generic account for all users.

Here's the test code, cobbled together from several answers on here. All signs suggest it should work, but I still get a 401-unauthorized error. at the getResponse

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net;

namespace NetCredentialsTest
{
public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string theURL = "http://webaddress.com:12345/subsite/dir";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Uri requestUri = null;
        Uri.TryCreate(theURL, UriKind.Absolute, out requestUri);


        //NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        //CredentialCache cache = new CredentialCache();
        //cache.Add(requestUri, "Basic", nc);

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(requestUri);

        /* http://mark.michaelis.net/Blog/CallingWebServicesUsingBasicAuthentication.aspx */
        byte[] credentialBuffer = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes("username" + ":" + "password");
        request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(credentialBuffer);

        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        // Display the status.
        Console.WriteLine(response.StatusDescription);
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();


        libResults.Text = responseFromServer;
        // Cleanup the streams and the response.
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
    }
}
}
```

I don't want to simply open it up to anonymous access. I suspect there's more that needs doing because it's a SharePoint site, but I'm unsure what.

The credential seems to be getting built right, but there may be more ways to test it that I don[t know.

Comment: I'm guessing you have basic authentication turned on in IIS. What data are you trying to retrieve? There is a slew of SharePoint methodologies that you can use to gather the data you need using CSOM: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee537247(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Actually, after getting into the site, I see this site is using windows integrated authentication, which certainly changes the code I've got, and might throw a monkey wrench into it altogether.  let me back up a bit - maybe I'm just overcomplicating my solution.  I want to access results from the advanced search engine; I have a page built that gives me the results formatted as I need it. It seems simpler than hitting the listserv functions and doing the formatting on the client side, but maybe I'm wrong.